# Developing Excel 2007 Document-Level Solution in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, excel-2007, compatibility

The Visual Studio 2013 documentation does not list Excel 2007 as one of the versions supported in the document-level customization solutions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942839.aspx

If I go the route of a document-level customization solution I will need it to be able to be deployed to Excel 2007 because that is the version of Office the users will have.

Do I need to develop in an earlier version of Visual Studio to get this to work? - or can I develop Excel 2007 document solutions in Visual Studio 2013? If so, will I need office 2007 installed on my development machine?

A similar question has been asked regarding Visual Studio 2012 below:
[VSTO 2012: backward compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074508/vsto-2012-backward-compatibility)

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that VS2013 just flat out won't support Office 2007 interops.  While the answer I provided on the question you link to works in VS2012, VS2013 insists on upgrading the project file which updates office references to Office 2013 versions.  Looks like they specifically exclude Office 2007 in VS2013 where they didn't in VS2012.